# MS Access - Validation rule for unbound text box

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a *Textbox2* in *FormX* which updates after I enter the value in *Textbox1* using Afterupdate for *Textbox1*.
*Textbox2* is unbounded text box.

Now I am trying to set up validation rule for the text in *Textbox2*. If Textbox2 contains word "Hold", it should pop up a message box saying "Invalid Entry".

Is it something possible? I could not find any reference online.
Can anyone please help?
Thank you,

Comment: Use textbox Validation Rule and Validation Text properties. If you want to allow Null: `NOT LIKE "*Hold*" Or Is Null`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Including code would be nice, but based on what you wrote, I would think you could add a check to your after update event in textbox 1 that occurs after the text is written to textbox 2 that will fire off the msgbox if it is invalid and then clear the entry in textbox 1.

```
Private Sub Textbox1_AfterUpdate()
    If Textbox1.Value = "abc" Then
        Textbox2.Value = "hold"
    End If
    
    If Textbox2.Value = "hold" Then
        MsgBox "Invalid Entry", vbOKOnly, "Wrong!"
        Textbox1.Value = ""
    End If
End Sub
```